# Stop reloading page when axios.get is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have class which has `btn` (icon of fontawesome) and `axios.get` is called when button is clicked.

click -> axios.get() -> get API response

It works fine, but somehow, browser is refreshed API response is received.

How can I stop this? It would be great if someone could tell me why it reloads.

I'm using server `npm start` I am using `Material-UI` is it relevant with?

```
class ParamBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleRadioChange = this.handleRadioChange.bind(this);
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name:"paramboard",
      radio:0,
      loading:0
    };
  }
  handleRadioChange(value){
    this.setState({radio:value});
    console.log(value);
    console.log(this.state.radio);
  }
  click(){
    console.log("submit clicked:" + this.state.radio);
    if (this.state.radio == 0){
      console.log("no genre;");
      return;
    }
    this.setState(state => ({ loading: 1 }));
      axios.get('http://localhost:8000/defapp/createsong',{
        params: {
          genre: this.state.radio,
        }
      }).then((res)=> {
        console.log(res.data);// this is shown on console but soon reloaded.
        this.state.loading = 0;
      }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
  }
  render() {
    let btnClass;    
      if (this.state.loading == 1){
        btnClass = "fas fa-5x fa-circle-notch fa-spin";
      }
      else {
        btnClass = "fas fa-5x fa-microphone-alt";
      }
  
    return (
      <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
      <GenreRadio onValueChange={this.handleRadioChange}></GenreRadio>
      </GridItem>
     <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
     <Card><CardBody>
     <div>
      <i onClick = {() => this.click()} id="createBtn" className={btnClass}></i>
      </div>
     
     </CardBody></Card>
     </GridItem>
     </GridContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is solved.

This API made the file and put this in `/public` folder so page is reloaded.

I'm not sure where should I put the dynamically generated file in React.js project, but the reason for reloading is found.

Comment: `this.state.loading = 0;` is a no-no in React. Never mutate state, always use `setState`. Not sure how the entire browser page is refreshed though, would need a [mcve] for that.

Comment: reload the problem is solved. I updated the article

Comment: It seems like the answer has nothing to do with how the problem was solved. That's quite misleading for future visitors looking for answers...

Comment: In addition to the above comment, it's better to [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) than do an "EDIT: here's my solution" into the question. Answers go in answers, questions go in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly start by removing this, because react practices immutability

```
this.state.loading = 0;
```

instead do this, if you must change the this.state object

```
this.setState({loading:0});
```

then this also,

```
if (this.state.radio == 0){
      console.log("no genre;");
      return;
    }
    this.setState(state => ({ loading: 1 }));
```

I'd advise you make the setState this below:

```
  this.setState({ loading: 1 });
```

Then, also check if you may have any component or logic, causing a constant loop, probably affecting the state